# Expanding bash variable within a string

Tags: json, bash, jq, variable-expansion

I am trying to get a variable within a string to expand - its a path:

/path/to/${variable}/here

1. The string originates in a json file.
2. It is subsequently read by jq - at this point I need the expansion to occur.

Here is the json file:

```
{
    "server_1":{
      "tag": "storage_1",
      "user": "me",
      "sshKey": "/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa",
      "target_folder": "/Users/me/Desktop/",
      "pubIp": "127.0.0.1",
      "data_folders": [
        "/Users/me/Desktop/POD_INSTALLS/pod_DB/${BUILD_FOLDER}/data/table1/",
        "/Users/me/Desktop/POD_INSTALLS/pod_DB/${BUILD_FOLDER}/data/table2/"
      ]
    }
}
```

Here is the jq code (now with working code - thanks all):

```
  writeFolder=$(jq -r --arg bf "${BUILD_FOLDER}" '.server_'${id}'.data_folders[] | sub("\\${BUILD_FOLDER}";$bf)' "${json_path}")
  for folder in $writeFolder
  do
    ssh -q -o ForwardX11=no -i ${sshKey} ${user}@${pubIp} "mkdir -p ${folder}"
  done
```

Originally - within the expanded $writeFolder variable, the path could be seen but the ${BUILD_FOLDER} variable remained unexpanded as it was taken literally. (when I used set -x I could see it was surrounded by single quotes).

Eventually used accepted solution from peak to make better use of jq.

Comment: In the example shown there are only two paths inside `data_folders`, so are you planning to do `2-3` and get  `-1` for the value of `numberOfDataFolders`?

Comment: In the JSON you show, `data_folders` is a sibling, not a member, of `server_1`.

Comment: You can also push more work into `jq`, avoiding shell interpolation and pipelines. For example, `numberOfDataFolders=$( jq --arg id "$id" '.["server_" + $id].data_folders | length - 3')`.

Comment: I think I have seen a similar question, but I cannot find it anymore. The easy but dangerous solution would be something like `eval expandedString="$stringWithVariableInside"`.

Comment: thanks for all your comments - I have corrected my original dodgy copy and paste and have added a working solution suggested by peak.

Comment: Please note that the revised script above won’t work if the paths have embedded spaces, which is not so uncommon these days; that’s why it’s better to use `read -r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you'd be much better off making jq do as much work as possible.  But to use jq, you'll need to fix the JSON.  Also, it's not clear to me that you need to compute $numberOfDataFolders at all, so in the interests of simplicity, this is what I'd suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash

json_path=input.json

BUILD_FOLDER=mybuildfolder

jq -r --arg bf "$BUILD_FOLDER" '.data_folders[] | sub("\\${BUILD_FOLDER}";$bf)' "${json_path}" |
  while read -r writeFolder
    do
    echo mkdir -p "${writeFolder}"
  done
```

Once the input has been fixed, this produces:

```
mkdir -p /Users/me/Desktop/POD_INSTALLS/pod_DB/mybuildfolder/data/table1/
mkdir -p /Users/me/Desktop/POD_INSTALLS/pod_DB/mybuildfolder/data/table2/
```

Notice also that the -r option circumvents the need to use `tr`.